# Рекомендации по моему первому коду PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, написал свой небольшой проект на Laravel.

Можно ли от вас ребята получить небольшую обратную связь по моему первому коду в Laravel? По каким-то банальным моментам что то может не так сделал?

Основной код у меня в тут в модели [User](https://github.com/lagavu/timetable/blob/master/app/User.php)

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'timetable_users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'morning_work_hours_from', 'morning_work_hours_before', 'afternoon_work_hours_from', 'afternoon_work_hours_before',
    ];

    public function holiday()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Holiday::class);
    }

    public function party()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Party::class);
    }

    // Получение графика отпусков сотрудника
    public function getHolidays($id)
    {
        $holidays = DB::table('timetable_holidays')
            ->where('user_id', '=', $id)
            ->get();
        return $holidays;
    }

    // Получение праздников России с названием
    public function NameHolidaysRu()
    {
        $apiDate = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/russian__ru%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyC8khrJO57yl4szjLOuyQrlW7R_CKgwaH0'), 1);
        $holidayDates = Arr::pluck($apiDate['items'], 'start.date');
        $nameHolidayDates = Arr::pluck($apiDate['items'], 'summary');
        $count = count($holidayDates);

        $dateAndName = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $dateAndName[] = [
                    "date" => $holidayDates[$i],
                    "name_holiday" => $nameHolidayDates[$i]
                ];
        }
        return $dateAndName;
    }

    // Получение праздников России
    public function getApiHolidays()
    {
        $apiDate = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/russian__ru%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyC8khrJO57yl4szjLOuyQrlW7R_CKgwaH0'), 1);
        $holidayDates = Arr::pluck($apiDate['items'], 'start.date');

        $array = array_filter($holidayDates, function ($var) {
            return substr($var, 0, 4) === date("Y");
        });
        return $array;
    }

    // Получение периода дат из формы
    public function getPeriodDateForm($startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $startDate = new Carbon($startDate);
        $endDate = new Carbon($endDate);

        $allDates = array();

        while ($startDate->lte($endDate)) {
            $allDates[] = $startDate->toDateString();
            $startDate->addDay();
        }
        return $allDates;
    }

// Добавление отпускных дат сотрудника в массив
    public function getDateHolidayArr($holidaysEmployee)
    {
        $allHolidays = array();

        $count = count($holidaysEmployee);
        if ($count == 0)
        {
            return $allHolidays;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $holidaysFrom = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_from;
            $holidaysBefore = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_before;

            $startDate = new Carbon($holidaysFrom);
            $endDate = new Carbon($holidaysBefore);

            while ($startDate->lte($endDate)) {
                $allHolidays[] = $startDate->toDateString();

                $startDate->addDay();
            }
        }
        return $allHolidays;
    }

    // Получение дат праздников которые будут удалены
    public function delPartyDays()
    {
        $getAllParties = $this->allParties();
        $allTotalParties = array();
        $count = count($getAllParties);

        if ($count == 0) {
            return $allTotalParties;
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $partiesFrom = $getAllParties[$i]['party_day_from'];
            $partiesBefore = $getAllParties[$i]['party_day_before'];

            $startDate = new Carbon($partiesFrom);
            $endDate = new Carbon($partiesBefore);

            while ($startDate->lte($endDate)) {
                $allTotalParties[] = $startDate->toDateString();
                $startDate->addDay();
            }
        }
        $firstDate = Arr::pluck($getAllParties, ['party_day_from']);
        $resultDate = array_diff($allTotalParties, $firstDate);

        return $resultDate;
    }

    // Получение выходных дней
    public function weekend($startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $start = strtotime($startDate);
        $end = strtotime($endDate);
        $result = array();

        while ($start <= $end)
        {
            if (date('N', $start) >= 6)
            {
                $current = date('Y-m-d', $start);
                $result[] = $current;
            } $start += 86400;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    // Получение расписания работника
    public function calculate($id, $startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $periodDateForm = $this->getPeriodDateForm($startDate, $endDate);
        $holidaysEmployee = $this->getHolidays($id);
        $allDateHolidaysEmployee = $this->getDateHolidayArr($holidaysEmployee);
        $allRuHolidays = $this->getApiHolidays();
        $allPartyDays = $this->delPartyDays();
        $allWekend = $this->weekend($startDate, $endDate);

        return array_diff($periodDateForm, $allDateHolidaysEmployee, $allRuHolidays, $allPartyDays, $allWekend);
    }

    // Получение всех праздников компании
    public function allParties()
    {
        $parties = Party::get();

        $subset = $parties->map(function ($party) {
            return $party->only(['name', 'party_day_from', 'party_day_before', 'party_time_from', 'party_time_before']);
        });
        return $subset;
    }

    // Формат даты для view
    public function formatDate($date)
    {
        return date('d.m.Y', strtotime($date));
    }

    // Проверка даты в JSON
    public function checkDateJson($s)
    {
        $allParties = $this->allParties();

        foreach ($allParties as $party) {
            $dateTimeParties = Arr::only($party, ['party_day_from', 'party_time_from']);

            if ($s === $dateTimeParties['party_day_from']) {
                $s = $dateTimeParties;
            }
        }
        return $s;
    }

    // Поления первых дат праздников компании
    public function partyDateJson($s)
    {
        $allParties = $this->allParties();
        $allDate = Arr::pluck($allParties, 'party_day_from');

        if (is_array($s) && in_array($s['party_day_from'], $allDate))
        {
            return $s['party_day_from'];
        } else {
            return $s;
        }
    }

    // Максимальное время первой половины дня
    public function maxMorningHour()
    {
        $maxMorningHour = DB::table('timetable_users')
            ->max('morning_work_hours_before');
        return $maxMorningHour;
    }


    // Время для JSON с учетом праздников
    public function partyTimeJson($s, $range)
    {
        if (!is_array($s))
        {
            return $range;
        }
        else {
            foreach ($range as $val)
            {
                if ($s['party_time_from'] < $val['end']
                    && $s['party_time_from'] > $val['start']
                    && $this->maxMorningHour() > $s['party_time_from'])
                {
                    $range = [
                        ['start' => $this->morning_work_hours_from, 'end' => $s['party_time_from']],

                    ];
                    return $range;
                    break;
                }
                elseif ($s['party_time_from'] < $range[1]['end']
                    && $s['party_time_from'] > $range[1]['start'])
                {
                    $range = [
                        ['start' => $this->morning_work_hours_from, 'end' => $this->morning_work_hours_before],
                        ['start' => $this->afternoon_work_hours_from, 'end' => $s['party_time_from']]
                    ];
                    return $range;
                    break;
                }
                return $range;
            }
        }
    }

    // Получить JSON
    public function getJSON($shedule)
    {
        $range = [
                  ['start' => $this->morning_work_hours_from, 'end' => $this->morning_work_hours_before] ,
                  ['start' => $this->afternoon_work_hours_from, 'end' => $this->afternoon_work_hours_before]
            ];
        $data = array_map(function($s) use ($range){
                     return [
                            'day' => $this->partyDateJson($this->checkDateJson($s)),
                            'timeRangers' => $this->partyTimeJson($this->checkDateJson($s), $range)
                        ];
                  }, $shedule);
        $result = ['schedule' => $data];
        return json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
```

Небольшой [контроллер](https://github.com/lagavu/timetable/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/TimetableController.php)

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Holiday;
use App\Party;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TimetableController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $countUser = User::All()->count();
        return view('timetable', compact('countUser'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'userId'=>'required|integer|exists:timetable_users,id',
            'startDate' => 'required|date',
            'endDate' => 'required|date|after:startDate'
        ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        $id = $request['userId'];
        $startDate = $request['startDate'];
        $endDate = $request['endDate'];
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $holidays = Holiday::findOrFail($id)->where("user_id", $id)->get()->sort();
        $parties = Party::all();
        $countUser = User::All()->count();
        $calculate = $user->calculate($id, $startDate, $endDate);

        return view('timetable', compact('holidays', 'user', 'countUser', 'parties', 'calculate'));

    }
}
```

И [вид](https://github.com/lagavu/timetable/blob/master/resources/views/timetable.blade.php)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <!-- Fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
            <h2>Расписание работника компании</h2>
        <hr>
        <h5>В вашей компании работает {{ $countUser }} сотрудников</h5>
        <hr>
        @if(count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert  alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
            <br>
        <form method="get"  action="{{ route('timetable.store') }}">
            <div class="row  align-items-end">
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <label>ID user</label>
                    <input type="text" name="userId" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="{{ old('userId') }}" id="userId">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <label>Дата, от</label>
                    <input type="date" name="startDate" class="form-control" value="{{ old('startDate') }}" id="start_date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <strong>Дата, до</strong>
                    <input type="date" name="endDate" class="form-control" value="{{ old('endDate') }}" id="end_date">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-submit">Расчитать</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
            <br>
            <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        @if ($user ?? '')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <h5 class="font-weight-bolder">Информация о работнике:</h5>
                <table class="table mt-5">
                    <thead>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">IdUser</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">График работы:</td>
                        <td>c {{ $user->morning_work_hours_from }} до {{ $user->morning_work_hours_before }} <br>
                            c {{ $user->afternoon_work_hours_from }} до {{ $user->afternoon_work_hours_before }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">Отпуск:</td>
                        <td>
                            @if($holidays->count() == 0)
                                У данного сотрудника отпуск не указан
                            @else
                                @foreach ($holidays as $holiday)
                                от {{  $user->formatDate($holiday->holidays_from) }} до {{ $user->formatDate($holiday->holidays_before) }} <br>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br>
                <table class="table mt-5">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Праздник компании</th>
                        <th scope="col">Начало</th>
                        <th scope="col">Окончание</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach ($parties as $party)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $party->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->formatDate($party->party_day_from) }} {{ $party->party_time_from }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->formatDate($party->party_day_before) }} {{ $party->party_time_before }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br>
                <table class="table mt-5">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Праздники России за 2019</th>
                        <th scope="col">Дата</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach ($user->NameHolidaysRu() as $rusHoliday)
                        <tr>
                            @if ($rusHoliday['date'] > date("Y") && $rusHoliday['date'] < date('Y', strtotime('+1 years')))
                                <td> {{ $rusHoliday['name_holiday']}} </td>
                                <td> {{ $user->formatDate($rusHoliday['date']) }} </td>
                            @endif
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <h5 class="font-weight-bolder">JSON</h5>
                <p>Выходные дни не учитываются</p>
                 <pre>
                     {{ $user->getJSON($calculate) }}
                 </pre>
            </div>

        </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Буду рад любым комментариям

PS на выходе то что требовалось реализовать по ТЗ все сделал, все работает.

Comment: И сразу вопрос - почему в модели User находятся какие-то несвязанные с ним вещи типа выходных и прочего?

Comment: благодарю.. раскидал по необходимым моделям нужные функции но как мне теперь обратиться например к методу который находится теперь в другой модели? Сейчас у меня есть функция в User в которой необходимо использовать метод из Holiday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вся логика у вас в модели User. Это неверно, в модели должна быть только логика обработки полей модели.

---

Логику работы со сторонним сервисом лучше вынести в отдельный класс(например сервис GoogleApiService)

---

Логику выборок лучше вынести в отдельный класс, например UserRepository и реализовать в нем метод getUserHolidays()

---

Метод преобразования даты $user->formatDate($holiday->holidays_from) должен быть в модели Holiday

```
public function getFormatDate(): string
{
    return date('d.m.Y', strtotime($this->holidays_from));
}
```

---

Часть методов у вас с префиксом get(getHolidays), часть без(weekend, хотя тоже что то возвращает), часть с большой буквы(NameHolidaysRu) - надо определиться с неймингом.

---

Вместо кострукции

```
DB::table('timetable_holidays')->where('user_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

Лучше использовать

```
Holiday::query()->where('user_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

Чтобы не дублировать название таблицы, которое и так указано в модели.

---

Значения типа адреса сервиса https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3... и его параметры лучше вынести в конфиг(.env)

---

Не используйте название переменных, которые поймете только вы

```
public function partyDateJson($s)
```

---

Используйте type hinting

---

Валидацию в контроллере лучше вынести в Form Request https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: Роман огромное спасибо за фидбек! Проработаю обязательно все эти моменты!